# Usage of 'much' without 'how'

Tags: word-choice

My apologies if the title is not clean. This is my first question here.

I work in an IT company and recently came across a requirement for one of our customer facing emails.

One line in the email read -

> Click below to apply now and see much extra money could be yours.

I wonder if skipping the word 'how', just before 'much' here is correct.

I feel the sentence should have been -

> Click below to apply now and see how much extra money could be yours.

The team that gave this requirement says that it is creative writing, but I am not convinced.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would say "that" was omitted, not "how".  I would not say it needs to be changed.

Comment: Thanks for the response GEdgar, but I don't feel that is how they meant it to be either.

There is another line at a different part of the email that reads - 

> Check now to see how much you can get.

Comment: You’re absolutely correct here: as it stands, it’s not creative writing, just ungrammatical. “See much extra money could be yours” is not English.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it is creative writing in any way. The sentence structure seems to be incomplete and the usage of the word 'how' improves the structure.

As per the comment by GEdgar, the sentence would become 'Click below to apply now and see that much extra money could be yours.' To me, this sentence sounds as if someone's trying to allure you into clicking the link (usually found in spam emails).

I might be wrong since I do not know the entire context of the requirement, but most certainly 'how much' certainly sounds correct.

Comment: Please do not write personal comments in answers, especially when the answers don't answer the question.